# I'm trying to assign zero into a 2D array in C

Tags: c, for-loop, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation, function-definition

I'm trying to assign zero into the values of the 2D array -- array_pointer. However, I seem to get a segmentation fault. I'm at a loss why, am I indexing into the array in the wrong manner?

```
int **alloc_grid(int width, int height)
{
    int **array_pointer;
    int i;
    int j;
    
    array_pointer = malloc(sizeof(int *) * (width * height));
    if (array_pointer == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    if (width <= 0 || height <= 0)
        return (NULL);
    for (i = 0; i < width; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < height; j++)
            array_pointer[i][j] = 0;
    return (array_pointer);
}
```

Comment: Besides all the other comments that are true you may also want to do array_pointer[i][j] = 0; using the actual index and not the "size".

Comment: @OlamideOlanrewaju You may not know the answer to this, but are you trying to allocate a true, two-dimensional array, or a simulated one using pointers to pointers?  Your `malloc` call and nested loop suggest the former, while your declarations `int **` suggest the latter.  See also [Question 6.16](https://c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldy.html) in the [C FAQ list](https://c-faq.com)

Comment: @Simone-Cu Yes! I just noticed that. Ridiculous that I missed that.

Comment: @SteveSummit The links you provided really helped to clear things up. And it seems to be a useful resource going forward. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You dynamically allocated a one-dimensional array of pointers. The pointers were not initialized. So you may not dereference them as you are doing

```
array_pointer[width][height] = 0;
```

Moreover you are always using the same indices in this statement.

Also this if statement

```
if (width <= 0 || height <= 0)
    return (NULL);
```

can result in a memory leak. You need at first check arguments and only after that to allocate memory.

The function can look the following way. I assume that the variable height means the number of rows and the variable width means the number of elements in each row.

```
int ** alloc_grid( size_t height, size_t width )
{
    int **array_pointer = NULL;
    
    if ( height != 0 && width != 0 )
    {
        array_pointer = malloc( height * sizeof(int *) );

        if ( array_pointer != NULL )
        {
            size_t i = 0;

            while ( i < height && ( array_pointer[i] = calloc( width, sizeof( int ) ) ) != NULL )
            {
                ++i;
            }

            if ( i != height )
            {
                while ( i != 0 ) free( array_pointer[--i] );
                free( array_pointer );
                array_pointer = NULL;
            }
        }
    }

    return array_pointer;     
}
```